# Closures in a class scope

Tags: python, class, scope

From my understanding, function and class scopes behave pretty much the same:

```
>>> def x():
...     a = 123
...     print (locals())
... 
>>> x()
{'a': 123}


>>> class x():
...     a = 123
...     print (locals())
... 
{'a': 123, '__module__': '__main__'}
```

When, however, I define a closure, behaviors are different. A function simply returns the local binding, as expected:

```
>>> def x():
...     a = 123
...     t = lambda: a
...     return t
... 
>>> x()()
123
```

whereas in a class the binding appears to be lost:

```
>>> class x():
...     a = 123
...     t = lambda self: a
... 
>>> x().t()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <lambda>
NameError: global name 'a' is not defined
```

Can anyone explain the discrepancy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class scope is a *temporary* scope, it only exists while executing the body of the class definition. The resulting `dict` is used to create the class namespace, the `__dict__` of the class.

As far as functions defined in a class are concerned, the next scope 'up' is the scope of the `class` definition itself.

The following works fine:

```
>>> def foo():
...     spam = 'eggs'
...     class Bar(object):
...         def baz(self): return spam
...     return Bar()
... 
>>> foo().baz()
'eggs'
```

This is documented in [pep 227](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0227/):

> Names in class scope are not accessible.  Names are resolved in
>       the innermost enclosing function scope.  If a class definition
>       occurs in a chain of nested scopes, the resolution process skips
>       class definitions.

and in the [`class` compound statement documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#class-definitions):

> The class’s suite is then executed in a new execution frame (see section [*Naming and binding*](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html#naming)), using a newly created local namespace and the original global namespace. (Usually, the suite contains only function definitions.) When the class’s suite finishes execution, **its execution frame is discarded but its local namespace is saved**. [[4]](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#id8) A class object is then created using the inheritance list for the base classes and the saved local namespace for the attribute dictionary.

Emphasis mine; the execution frame is the temporary scope.

Comment: After the class body has been executed, anything in the scope is stuffed in the class `__dict__` and then deleted. So `a` is not bound when you run `t`.

Comment: @katrielalex: exactly, that's what I meant with `used to create the class namespace`.

Comment: @katrielalex: Note that `a` being bound just means that *a* scope has it in it's `locals()` dictionary. `globals()` is just the module `locals()`, really.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by a "temporary" scope (are there "permanent" scopes?), but at the moment `t = lambda: a` is being executed, `a` does exist. So the closure is aware of this binding, but somehow loses it later.

Comment: @thg435: What makes you think  "the closure is aware of this binding"? You can define `t = lambda: a` in python at any time, the existence of `a` is not verified. With "temporary" I mean that the scope only exists until the last statement in the `class` block has been executed, after which the resulting `locals()` dict is used to create the `class` instance and is no longer available to contained scopes.

Comment: Isn't the function's execution frame also temporary?  According to PEP 227 (which you linked), the reason for not allowing methods to close over class variables is more for consistency with the way "self" is used to access attributes rather than any technical issue.

Comment: @CS: I didn't say it was a technical reason, I just stated that the class scope should be seen as temporary. Sure, you could give the contained function objects closures to access the class attributes, but that'd cause a lot of scoping confusion. A class namespace can only be accessed via explicit references instead (via `type(self).class_attr`, `ClassName.class_attr` or via `self.class_attr`, provided there is no masking name on the instance).